# Error on a view MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using MVC 4 and i've created a controller with read/write actions and views using EF. I've created a new view (so now i have index, details, edit, delete, create and newview) and the new view has the exact same code as the index but when i try to acess the new view it gives this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   App_Web_hcu5njnc.dll but was not handled in user code

The code of the view (same has index but without the create edit details links):

```
@model IEnumerable<GestorSalas.Models.Horario>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProcurarSalas";
}

<h2>Procurar Salas</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Disciplina.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sala.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dia)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HoraEntrada)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HoraSaida)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Disciplina.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sala.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dia)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraEntrada)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraSaida)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Can someone help me? Why it gives that error?
Those parameters already have data, they are not empty

Comment: Show the relevant code (the model and the GET method)

Comment: The reason might be either you are not passing model with current type.i.e you need to pass IEnumerable<Models.Harario> or the properties model.Sala and model.Displina can be null or final chance would be because of model properties that are outside foreach loop